# Running MVC application on IIS without domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

My application contains lots of links to the root ("/login/dologin"). When I'm running the application under a domain, there's no problem.

Right now I'm moving to a new server, and I can't test my application. My application sits in "localhost/md", I need the link to go to "localhost/md/login/dologin". Instead, it goes to "localhost/login/dologin", and, ofcourse, the resource cannot be found.

What do I need to configure on my IIS to make this works without domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a guess, since you haven't posted any of your configuration.

In your authentication element in the web.config, do you have the route to the login page specified as `/login/dologin`? could you try `~/login/dologin`

The second option, should give you a relative path from the home of the virtual directory application, rather than going to the root of the 'site'

For referencing files (e.g. javascript & css) you could do `@Url.Content("~/path/to/file.js")`

**EDIT:** *Based on additional comments*

in Layout.cshtml...

```
var SITE_ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")'
```

then in your JS file use SITE_ROOT as a prefix in your routes

```
var url = SITE_ROOT + "Home/Index";
```

Comment: I don't have any specific configuration for this matter. I can change the links in my application using @url.action, but what would I do in js files?

Comment: for js files, you could use `@Url.Content("~/path/to/file.js")` in your layout and views

Comment: I ment what do I do INSIDE js file (when I can't use the html helper)

Comment: oh, you would need to create a site root variable in your layout and reference it from within your js file. I'll add an example to my answer

Comment: @Shahar - Can you give an example of how you *need* to use an explicit path in your javascript?